# Network request not occurring after app is coming out of suspended state into applicationDidBecomeActive state

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

When my phone is idle for an extended period of time and receives a push from the app I want to be able to Open the app and perform a network function. This generally works. I am posting a notification from the applicationDidBecomeActive in the main application view, so when its opened it will perform a function. This works fine, but when the phone has been idle for an extended period of time It does not work. The function fires, but I am getting a nil response. I am using Alamofire to make the request. I tried setting a delay on the function thinking this may help, but it seemed to make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by performing the network request in the app delegate applicationDidBecomeActive and then posting a notification when it finishes to update my tableview data as opposed to posting the notification to the tableview and having it perform the networkrequest.